# how to create linked server in MS SQL Server to Netezza

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, netezza

How can I create a linked server from SQL Server 2008 to Netezza?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Netezza IBM ODBC driver for netezza installed on the MS Sql Server machine, you may be able to connect it up.

This link gives an overview of how to do it for MySQL, it may work, with some adjustments, for Netezza. (for example, instead of a Mysql DSN, you would create a Netezza DSN).

Your mileage may vary, however, and I have not tried this.

http://www.ideaexcursion.com/2009/02/25/howto-setup-sql-server-linked-server-to-mysql/